# How can i found my ip without using websites

Tags: ip, external

I know there is websites to show my external IP like whatsmyip.org. but what if port 80 is blocked in my system. is there any other ways to find my external ip like using CMD or other ports ?

Comment: With UNIX, you can try this : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-bash

Comment: tnx, thats linux command right? what about windows ? and what port these commands use to connect ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit : I post here because I can't comment again to answer the second comment.

This command (dig) use the port 53 (the default value is the standard DNS port). If you want you can change the port using -p. About Windows, I don't know, sorry.